# How to set a value to another elements height

Tags: jquery, css, height

I have a list of images on my website, and I because of different resolutions on viewers screens, the total height of the div changes. I need to set the "top" value as the height of ".photoswrap".
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot give a working answer with seeing the code, but:

```
var $someDiv = $('div');
$someDiv.css('top', $('.photoswrap', $someDiv).height());
```

Or if `.photoswrap` is not inside of the div specifically:

```
$('div').css('top', $('.photoswrap').height());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $("#something").css("top", $(".photoswrap").css("height"));
```